# Validate form with bootstrap (novalidate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a problem validating a form with bootstrap novalidate.
Some form fields include the "required" tag and others do not.

To verify, I submit the form with no data and the 'was-validated' class makes all the fields validated, the ones with the "required" tag are marked in red and the others in green.

The idea is to specify which fields to validate instead of the entire form.

Could you help me please?

Form

```
<form id="Data" method="POST" class="needs-validation mt-0" novalidate>
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="d-block font-weight-semibold">Name: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- / col -->
    </div> <!-- / row-->
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="d-block font-weight-semibold">Lastname: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- / col -->
    </div> <!-- / row-->
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="d-block font-weight-semibold">Street: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="number" id="Street" name="Street" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- / col -->
    </div> <!-- / row-->
</form>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Data').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = document.getElementById('Data');
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                //url: "",
                type: $('#Data').attr('method'),
                data: $('#Data').serialize(),
                //dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function(){ },
                success:function(response) {
                    if (response.success == true) {
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        $('#Data').addClass('was-validated');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/33260

Answer (score 0):

Call checkValidity() for each field that need checking, not the complete form:

```js
    var formFlag = true;

    var nameField = document.getElementById("name");
    if (!nameField.checkValidity()) {
        nameField.classList.add("is-invalid");
        formFlag = false;
    }

    var lastnameField = document.getElementById("lastname");
    if (!lastnameField.checkValidity()) {
        lastnameField.classList.add("is-invalid");
        formFlag = false;
    }

    if (!formFlag) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
    } else {
```

Comment: I did what you indicated, I validated inside the `if (customField1.checkValidity() === false)` but it keeps validating all the fields.

Comment: The customFieldx stubs are only examples on how to handle validations that can not be covered by standard HTML5 validations. Since checkValidity() has already been called on the form there is no need to call it again on an invidual field within this form.

You will provide a better user-experience if you validate the whole form in one swoop instead having the user press submit again and again for each invalid field. In case you want to go this route anyway, do not call checkValidity() for the form itself but for each input field individually.

Comment: That if I understand, just leave the `customFieldx` variables to not write others and just replace the `getElementById` then I send them to the `if`. It is not to validate the whole form, since I only have two mandatory fields, they are the only ones, and since I use [Bootstrap Validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/), when I click save, the fields that are not mandatory recognize them as valid and mark them with a green border, it is that's why I want to remove that mark and leave only the two required fields.

Comment: @Alonso, I revised the answer.